# bin log dump - mysql master and slave

Tags: mysql, replication

I have some issues regarding the master-slave data replication, is there any chance to re-sync them in order to have the same data in both master and slave without trying to add manually data on slave to be the same with master?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to make a backup of the source and use it to replace the data on the replica entirely. This is reinitializing the replica.

The other option is to use Percona Toolkit tools like pt-table-checksum and pt-table-sync to do an incremental replacement of only the data that needs fixing.

See

- https://www.percona.com/blog/2015/08/12/mysql-replication-primer-with-pt-table-checksum-and-pt-table-sync/
- https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/03/17/mysql-replication-primer-with-pt-table-checksum-pt-table-sync-part-2/